# Airdrop from 1st gen iPad Mini to MacBookPro

Tags: ipad, macos, airdrop

I am trying to copy a photo that I just took with my 1st gen iPad mini (with iOS 8.2) onto my late 2011 MacBookPro (with 10.10.2) and I can't seem to use Airdrop. Is this a restriction of the OS or the hardware and is there any way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

No. iOS 8 will Airdrop to and receive from a Yosemite Mac. It is more likely that your iPad (Or Mac) is not compatible with the feature. If your iPad is older then a 4th gen, I think, it won't work.

Comment: Just as a side note, I've encountered a bug in which supported devices aren't discoverable. I just logged off my apple ID on the device(s) and logged back in to get it working.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I haven't used it enough to give thought to that. I have noticed it across iOS devices though.

Comment: It seems that it is a restriction on the MacBook, because the iPad works with the iPhone 5.